# Flutter. Firebase not initializing on android and web together

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web

This is working for web but not for android. And when i comment out **options:FirebaseOptions()** it works for android and not for web.

**Code: which works for web**

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: "---",
    appId: "---",
    messagingSenderId: "---",
    projectId: "---",
  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Error For android:** a firebase app named "[default]" already exists

**Code: which works for android**

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**Error for web:** FirebaseOptions cannot be null when creating the default app

Comment: Sorry, i got it. I'll post what worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "---",
      appId: "---",
      messagingSenderId: "---",
      projectId: "---",
    ));
  } else
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initFireBase();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}```
````